# Django File Upload With Veritication Doesn't Work

Tags: django, forms, validation

I am creating a website where user can upload music files and it will be saved in a directory. So i added the following html form:

```
<form action='upload/' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

I've successfully configured the urls to handle this request. Here's the view that this url points to:

```
def uploadMusic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse('Success')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Could not verify')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return HttpResponse('Failed')
```

Plus, i want this music file to be validated before saving it to the directory. I want the file size to be lesser than 4mb. In my forms.py file, i have added the following codes:

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()

    def clean(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data.get('file', False)
        if file:
            if file._size > 4*1024*1024:
                return 'Error'
            else:
                return file
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Wrong')
```

Ok so the problem is, i cannot get this working. I get no errors but the file is successfully uploaded despite its file size. 
PS: I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check you if else logic

```
 if file:
```

will be always true if any file comes in.

```
if file._size > 4*1024*1024:
   return 'Error'
```

will return Error string but will not raise any actual error
in short

```
else:
    raise forms.ValidationError('Wrong')
```

will never get executed

Comment: It worked. One quick question though, why do we pass 'file' in cleaned_data function? is it related to the form input name?